# Excluding Content From SQL Bulk Insert

Tags: sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I want to import my IIS logs into SQL for reporting using Bulk Insert, but the comment lines - the ones that start with a # - cause a problem becasue those lines do not have the same number f fields as the data lines.

If I manually deleted the comments, I can perform a bulk insert.

Is there a way to perform a bulk insert while excluding lines based on a match such as : any line that beings with a "#".

Thanks.

Comment: can you explain more for the reason when you said **I want to import my IIS logs into SQL for reporting**. can you explain more for your requirement?

Comment: See my .NET answer below. I'm also now investigating SSIS: you can exclude these rows by using a Conditional Split and setting the filter to `SUBSTRING(date,1,1) == "#"`. You then ignore this output and only use the default output. (This of course requires you to initially import all the columns as strings to avoid data-type conflicts with the comment rows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I generally use with `BULK INSERT` and irregular data is to push the incoming data into a temporary staging table with a single `VARCHAR(MAX)` column.

Once it's in there, I can use more flexible decision-making tools like SQL queries and string functions to decide which rows I want to select out of the staging table and bring into my main tables. This is also helpful because `BULK INSERT` can be maddeningly cryptic about the why and how of why it fails on a specific file.

The only other option I can think of is using pre-upload scripting to trim comments and other lines that don't fit your tabular criteria before you do your bulk insert.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [logparser.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659) instead. LogParser has some pretty [neat capabilities on its own](http://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/log-parser-rocks-more-than-50-examples/), but it can also be used to format the IIS log to be properly imported by SQL Server.

Comment: I find that LogParser is too slow when running across historical data (in this case 5GB). However, I have used a daily PowerShell script to call LogParser for the previous day's file and store the result in a SQL table. This way I can report on aggregate data quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on what PeterX wrote, I modified the application to handle large log files since anything sufficiently large would create an out-of-memory exception.  Also, since we're only interested in whether or not the first character  of a line starts with a hash, we can just use StartsWith() method on the read operation.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 2)
        {
            string path = args[0];
            string outPath = args[1];
            string line;

            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.log"))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(outPath, new FileInfo(file).Name), false))
                    {
                        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            if(!line.StartsWith("#"))
                            {
                                sw.WriteLine(line);
                            }
                        }                          
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Source and Destination Log Path required or too many arguments");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a tool called "PrepWebLog" http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296093 - which strips-out these hash/pound characters, however I'm running it now (using a PowerShell script for multiple files) and am finding its performance intolerably slow.

I think it'd be faster if I wrote a C# program (or maybe even a macro).

---

Update: PrepWebLog just crashed on me. I'd avoid it.

---

Update #2, I looked at PowerShell's Get-Content and Set-Content commands but didn't like the syntax and possible performance. So I wrote this little C# console app:

```
        if (args.Length == 2)
        {
            string path = args[0];
            string outPath = args[1];

            Regex hashString = new Regex("^#.+\r\n", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.log"))
            {
                string data;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
                {
                    data = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }

                string output = hashString.Replace(data, string.Empty);
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(outPath, new FileInfo(file).Name), false))
                {
                    sw.Write(output);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Source and Destination Log Path required or too many arguments");
        }
```

It's pretty quick.

---